# Notification API PagSeguro

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm doing an integration with PagSeguro to my site.

I set up the page to receive notification whenever the status of it is changed according to the code below.

```
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var notificationCode = Request.QueryString ["notificationCode"];
            var token = "***";
            var email = "********@live.com";

            if (notificationCode! = null)
            {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create ("? Email =" "https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/transactions/notifications/" + notificationCode + + e + "& token =" + token);
            request.method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse ();
            }
        }
```

I check if there is a notification code, if have any, it does a redirect in PagSeguro requesting XML of this notification. But I think this way is not correct.

I would like some help to make a GET request in PagSeguro with the link, and get this XML. Into the XML, i want to sabe status and reference of that XML into variables. (var status and var reference for example)

The status is within the node transaction

```
<transaction>
        <status> 3 </ status>
        <reference> 123 </ reference>
</transaction>
```

Someone please help me?